# Find $\min_{\ell}\{[r_\ell(T) \cup T]\}$

Tags: geometry, optimization

> A triangle $T$ is given in the plane with sides $30,40,50$. A second triangle $r_\ell(T)$ is created by reflecting $T$ about a line $\ell$. Find $\displaystyle \min_{\ell}\{[r_\ell(T) \cup T]\}$ where $[\cdot]$ denotes area.

After experimenting a little bit with different reflections, it seems that the angle bisector produces the minimum union. Although I haven't worked out a proof yet it seems likely. If this is the case I wonder what can be said about a scalene triangle in general. Note that this "minimum" $line$ is the closest possible line of symmetry for a scalene triangle. I am wondering if it is possible to determine the answer to this question and for the general case of a scalene triangle.

[image]